# In a matrix table in Power BI, how to make sure that the table doesn't calculate subtotals and totals for duplicates?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a matrix table in Power BI where the lowest heirarchy has 2 users with same product but for their manager, it needs to be only counted once. How can I do that in the matrix table?

When I was pulling the heirarchy from one table and sales from another, Power Bi was doing it on it's own but when sales is in the same table as the user heirarchy, it is simply taking a sum of all the sales when it should only sum once for cases when product is repeated for multiple users for the same manager.

[image: Refer Screenshot]

As seen in the image, manager's total should be 300 but Power BI sums it up to 400. How can I make sure that manager's total is taken as 300? I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you should remove the duplicate items related to manager "A" in the "Product" column. In the real scenario, you need to filter this way for each manager.

You can do this within Power Query:
(notice the table name 'SalesTable')

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SalesTable"]}[Content],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Manager] = "A"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Manager", type text}, {"User", type text}, {"Product", Int64.Type}, {"Sales", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Duplicate Removed" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type", {"Product"}),
    Sales = #"Duplicate Removed"[Sales],
    CustomSUM = List.Sum(Sales)
in
    CustomSUM
```